# Covering tests using wildcard path for test files in mocha integration tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

top.js

```
const opts       = require('minimist')(process.argv);
const failAfter  = Number(opts['fail-after'] );

function importTest(name, path) {
    describe(name, function() {
        require(path);
    }); 
}


describe('top', function() {
var fileMatches = null;
let failures = 0;

afterEach(function() {

    console.log(this.currentTest.state);
    if(this.currentTest.state == 'failed') {
        console.log("fail-after = " +failAfter);
        failures++;
        console.log("failures = " +failures);
        if(failures == failAfter){
            console.log('\nToo many failures, exiting...');
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
});

importTest("a",'./test/a/a.js');
importTest("b",'./test/b/b.js');
importTest("test",'./test/test.js');
importTest("test1",'./test/test1.js');

});
```

I am trying to wrap all my mocha integration tests written in different files in my 'top' describe(written above). The purpose of this is to stop the tests after a particular number of test case failures(specified by the user in 'fail-after').

To include all the tests I have to explicitly call importTest() and pass the path of each test file. I want to automate it, so that I do not have to give the path of each file and instead all the files in the directory and sub-directories are covered.

Can someone suggest a way to do the same?

I run my tests using command "mocha --fail-after=5 ./top.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the above problem by using the Glob npm module.

Solution:

top.js

```
const opts       = require('minimist')(process.argv);
const failAfter  = Number(opts['fail-after'] );

var Glob = require("glob");
var pattern = "*.js";
var options = {matchBase: true, nonull: true};

function importTest(name, path) {
    describe(name, function() {
        require(path);
    });
}


describe('top', function () {
    let failures = 0;

    afterEach(function () {

        console.log(this.currentTest.state);
        if (this.currentTest.state == 'failed') {
            failures++;
            console.log("failures = " + failures);
            if (failures == failAfter) {
                console.log('\nToo many failures, exiting...');
                process.exit(1);
            }
        }
    });

    function globArray(pattern, options) {
        var list = [];

        var pathList = Glob.sync(pattern, options);

        pathList.forEach(function (item) {
            list.push("./"+item);
        });
        return list;
    }


    var mg = globArray(pattern, options);

    for(var i=0; i<mg.length; i++) {
        importTest("sample", mg[i]);
    }

});
```